# Meteor 1.3: How to create a client only collection containing some fields from the users db collection?

Tags: meteor

I want to publish all the users to the client (which will eventually be only the 'profile' field of all the users):

The publication on the server looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function users() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

In my template I then have a subscription that looks like this:

```
Template.Users_show_page.onCreated(function usersShowPageCreated() {
    this.subscribe('users');
});
```

However the 'users' variable is not available and I still have to access the users via Meteor.users, such as in the following code:

```
Template.Users_show_page.helpers({
    users() {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
});
```

Why is this?

I think I need to create a client-side collection with my choice of name - i.e. 'users', and then I can access that collection.

Where do I do this and how do I make that sync with the users in the database?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you expected to be available. What made you think that such variable will be available? Can you elaborate on what you expected to happen?

Comment: I expected that in the users() function I would be able to return users.find(), instead of Meteor.users.find()

Comment: Well, the `users` collection is under the `Meteor` namespace, but you could always create a file-scope `users` variable. The publication updates a collection, it does not create any global variables. Anyway, what's wrong with using `Meteor.users`?

Comment: This is because in my mind I am publishing a string called 'users' from the server. And on the client I am subscribing to a string called 'users'. logically, I would want to access that subscription by the string 'users'

Comment: @MasterAM. Nothing, it just doesn't make sense. but thank you for your comment, i now know it DOESN'T create a global variable which I thought was happening

Comment: Glad to have helped. Publishing data as it is done now normally makes sense, but there are situations in which it can pose a problem (e.g, pagination when multiple publications publish to the same collection). In your use case it is fairly straightforward, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('foo');

Meteor.publish('myPublication', function() {
    return MyCollection.find();
});
```

The code above doesn't create a `myPublication` variable anywhere. It's just the name of the publication/subscription. You can even have multiple different subscriptions over the same collection. This code returns a cursor for the `foo` Mongo collection, which you access via MyCollection object.

So, your code doesn't need to create a new `Mongo.Collection`. Just use `Meteor.users` because that's the `Mongo.Collection` object that's already linked to "users" in MongoDB.

If you really want to access the documents in a users variable, you still need to create the helper as you suggested, although it's better you just use Meteor.users instead of the helper below:

```
Template.template_name.helpers({
    users: function(){ return Meteor.users.find() }
});
```